# Undefined index - get key - on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, error, product-attribute

I keep getting :

> Notice: Undefined index: from in /app/design/frontend/default/theme246k/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 1
>
> Notice: Undefined index: from in /app/design/frontend/default/theme246k/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 196

```
LINE 1: php if($_GET['from'] == "key") { 

LINE 196: php if($_GET['from'] == "key") {
```

If I remove one of them, the page is broken. If I remove both of them, the page is broken.

What to do?

Comment: make sure you have your "Add Secret Key to URLs" set to YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

`if($_GET['from'] == "key") {`

**to**

`if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('from') == "key") {`

Comment: Worked immediately. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check that you are getting "from" key in GET / POST request or not.

Also, you can use magento way to get parameters fo get or post a request.

```
$fromVar = $this->getRequest()->getParam("from", false);
if ($fromVar == 'key') {
 //Your logic goes here.
}
```